# Regular Expression to match 3 or more Consecutive Sequential Characters and Consecutive Identical Characters

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I need regular expressions to match the below cases.

1. 3 or more consecutive sequential characters/numbers; e.g. 123, abc, 789, pqr, etc.
2. 3 or more consecutive identical characters/numbers; e.g. 111, aaa, bbb, 222, etc.

Comment: If you want a regex which passes if the string does NOT contain 3 consecutive identical characters, you can use this: `/^(?!.*(.)\1\1.*).*$/` - https://regex101.com/r/hxTDfr/2

Answer (score 30):

I don't think you can (easily) use regex for the first case. The second case is easy though:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([a-z\\d])\\1\\1", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

Since `\\1` represents part matched by group `1` this will match any sequence of three identical characters that are either within the range `a-z` or are digits (`\d`).

**Update**

To be clear, you *can* use regex for the first case. However, the pattern is so laborious and ridiculously convoluted that you are better off not doing it at all. Especially if you wanted to REALLY cover all the alphabet. In that case you should probably generate the pattern programmatically by iterating the char codes of the Unicode charset or something like that and generate groupings for every three consecutive characters. However, you should realize that by having generated such a large decision tree for the pattern matcher, the marching performance is bound to suffer (`O(n)` where `n` is the number of groups which is the size of the Unicode charset minus 2).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22931991/regex-for-consecutive-numbers?lq=1 noted that it IS indeed possible to match an arbitrary length of sequential characters in a string, provided you define the rules for which characters follow which.

Comment: At least in Python/Perl regex, the "\\" would be "\"

Comment: In Python, to be able to forego the second backslash, you will need to start your string as a regex string with the r modifier (`r'...'` instead of `''`)

Answer (score 18):

I disagree, case 1 is possible to regex, but you have to tell it the sequences to match... which is kind of long and boring:

```
/(abc|bcd|cde|def|efg|fgh|ghi|hij|ijk|jkl|klm|lmn|mno|nop|opq|pqr|qrs|rst|stu|tuv|uvw|vwx|wxy|xyz|012|123|234|345|456|567|678|789)+/ig
```

http://regexr.com/3dqln

Answer (score 12):

for the second question:

```
\\b([a-zA-Z0-9])\\1\\1+\\b
```

**explanation:**

```
\\b               : zero-length word boundary
  (               : start capture group 1
    [a-zA-Z0-9]   : a letter or a digit
  )               : end group
  \\1             : same character as group 1
  \\1+            : same character as group 1 one or more times
\\b               : zero-length word boundary
```

Comment: That first part isn't sequential though.

Comment: Why are you using the word boundaries? I don't see the question stating that we are looking for word-wrap searches

Comment: @MiladNaseri to avoid matching `aaaaaaab`.

Comment: how can we convert it to less than 3?

Comment: @Saksham: Just remove the last `\\1+`.

Answer (score 11):

To my knowledge, the first case is indeed not possible. The regex engine doesn't know anything about the order of the natural numbers or the alphabet. But it's at least possible to differentiate between 3 or more numbers and 3 or more letters, for example:

```
[a-z]{3,}|[A-Z]{3,}|\d{3,}
```

This matches `abcd`, `ABCDE` or `123` but doesn't match `ab2d`, `A5c4` or `12z`, for example. According to this, the second case can be correctly given in a shorter version as:

```
  (\w)\1{2,}
```

Comment: `\w` includes also underscore `_`

Comment: Sure, but the author did not explicitly exclude punctuation. She only mentioned _identical characters_. This can be virtually everything. But anyway...

Answer (score 4):

> 3 or more consecutive sequential characters/numbers ex - 123, abc, 789, pqr etc.

Not possible with regular expressions.

> 3 or more consecutive identical characters/numbers ex - 111, aaa, bbb. 222 etc.

Use a [pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) of `(?i)(?:([a-z0-9])\\1{2,})*`.

If you want to check the whole string, use [`Matcher.matches()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches%28%29). To find matches within a string, use [`Matcher.find()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29).

Here's some sample code:

```
final String ps = "(?i)(?:([a-z0-9])\\1{2,})*";
final String psLong =
        "(?i)\t\t\t# Case insensitive flag\n"
                + "(?:\t\t\t\t# Begin non-capturing group\n"
                + " (\t\t\t\t# Begin capturing group\n"
                + "  [a-z0-9]\t\t# Match an alpha or digit character\n"
                + " )\t\t\t\t# End capturing group\n"
                + " \\1\t\t\t\t# Back-reference first capturing group\n"
                + " {2,}\t\t\t# Match previous atom 2 or more times\n"
                + ")\t\t\t\t# End non-capturing group\n"
                + "*\t\t\t\t# Match previous atom zero or more characters\n";
System.out.println("***** PATTERN *****\n" + ps + "\n" + psLong
        + "\n");
final Pattern p = Pattern.compile(ps);
for (final String s : new String[] {"aa", "11", "aaa", "111",
        "aaaaaaaaa", "111111111", "aaa111bbb222ccc333",
        "aaaaaa111111bbb222"})
{
    final Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    if (m.matches()) {
        System.out.println("Success: " + s);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Fail: " + s);
    }
}
```

And the output is:

```
***** PATTERN *****
(?i)(?:([a-z0-9])\1{2,})*
(?i)            # Case insensitive flag
(?:             # Begin non-capturing group
 (              # Begin capturing group
  [a-z0-9]      # Match an alpha or digit character
 )              # End capturing group
 \1             # Back-reference first capturing group
 {2,}           # Match previous atom 2 or more times
)               # End non-capturing group
*               # Match previous atom zero or more characters


Fail: aa
Fail: 11
Success: aaa
Success: 111
Success: aaaaaaaaa
Success: 111111111
Success: aaa111bbb222ccc333
Success: aaaaaa111111bbb222
```

Comment: Your first pattern will match characters that aren't sequential (ie. `vbgt`)

Comment: Oops, left that in. Corrected.

Comment: how to check if the string has a group of 3 or more similar characters consecutive (.....CCC....), string shouldnt have 3 consecutive similar characters. 
eg. it should not accept
1. AAA
2. AAAAAAA
3. AAAAR

Answer (score 3):

Thanks All for helping me.

For the first case - **3 or more consecutive sequential characters/numbers; e.g. 123, abc, 789, pqr, etc.** I used below code logic. Pls share your comments on this.

```
public static boolean validateConsecutiveSeq(String epin) {
    char epinCharArray[] = epin.toCharArray();
    int asciiCode = 0;
    boolean isConSeq = false;
    int previousAsciiCode = 0;
    int numSeqcount = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < epinCharArray.length; i++) {
        asciiCode = epinCharArray[i];
        if ((previousAsciiCode + 1) == asciiCode) {
            numSeqcount++;
            if (numSeqcount >= 2) {
                isConSeq = true;
                break;
            }
        } else {
            numSeqcount = 0;
        }
        previousAsciiCode = asciiCode;
    }
    return isConSeq;
}
```

Comment: the art is to write less code. in this case you need to find the proper regex.

Answer (score 3):

Regex to match three consecutive numbers or alphabets is
**"`([0-9]|[aA-zZ])\1\1`"**

Comment: Be aware that `[A-z]` matches more than letters, have a look at an ASCII table.

Answer (score 1):

If you have lower bound (3) and upper bound  regexString can be generated as follows

```
public class RegexBuilder {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        int seqStart = 3;
        int seqEnd = 5;
        buildRegex(sb, seqStart, seqEnd);
        System.out.println(sb);
    }

    private static void buildRegex(StringBuilder sb, int seqStart, int seqEnd) {
        for (int i = seqStart; i <= seqEnd; i++) {
            buildRegexCharGroup(sb, i, '0', '9');
            buildRegexCharGroup(sb, i, 'A', 'Z');
            buildRegexCharGroup(sb, i, 'a', 'z');
            buildRegexRepeatedString(sb, i);
        }
    }

    private static void buildRegexCharGroup(StringBuilder sb, int seqLength,
            char start, char end) {
        for (char c = start; c <= end - seqLength + 1; c++) {
            char ch = c;
            if (sb.length() > 0) {
                sb.append('|');
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < seqLength; i++) {
                sb.append(ch++);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void buildRegexRepeatedString(StringBuilder sb, int seqLength) {
        sb.append('|');
        sb.append("([a-zA-Z\\d])");
        for (int i = 1; i < seqLength; i++) {
            sb.append("\\1");
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
012|123|234|345|456|567|678|789|ABC|BCD|CDE|DEF|EFG|FGH|GHI|HIJ|IJK|JKL|KLM|LMN|MNO|NOP|OPQ|PQR|QRS|RST|STU|TUV|UVW|VWX|WXY|XYZ|abc|bcd|cde|def|efg|fgh|ghi|hij|ijk|jkl|klm|lmn|mno|nop|opq|pqr|qrs|rst|stu|tuv|uvw|vwx|wxy|xyz|([a-z\d])\1\1|0123|1234|2345|3456|4567|5678|6789|ABCD|BCDE|CDEF|DEFG|EFGH|FGHI|GHIJ|HIJK|IJKL|JKLM|KLMN|LMNO|MNOP|NOPQ|OPQR|PQRS|QRST|RSTU|STUV|TUVW|UVWX|VWXY|WXYZ|abcd|bcde|cdef|defg|efgh|fghi|ghij|hijk|ijkl|jklm|klmn|lmno|mnop|nopq|opqr|pqrs|qrst|rstu|stuv|tuvw|uvwx|vwxy|wxyz|([a-z\d])\1\1\1|01234|12345|23456|34567|45678|56789|ABCDE|BCDEF|CDEFG|DEFGH|EFGHI|FGHIJ|GHIJK|HIJKL|IJKLM|JKLMN|KLMNO|LMNOP|MNOPQ|NOPQR|OPQRS|PQRST|QRSTU|RSTUV|STUVW|TUVWX|UVWXY|VWXYZ|abcde|bcdef|cdefg|defgh|efghi|fghij|ghijk|hijkl|ijklm|jklmn|klmno|lmnop|mnopq|nopqr|opqrs|pqrst|qrstu|rstuv|stuvw|tuvwx|uvwxy|vwxyz|([a-z\d])\1\1\1\1
```

Answer (score 1):

All put together:

> ([a-zA-Z0-9])\1\1+|(abc|bcd|cde|def|efg|fgh|ghi|hij|ijk|jkl|klm|lmn|mno|nop|opq|pqr|qrs|rst|stu|tuv|uvw|vwx|wxy|xyz|012|123|234|345|456|567|678|789)+

3 or more consecutive sequential characters/numbers; e.g. 123, abc, 789, pqr, etc.

> (abc|bcd|cde|def|efg|fgh|ghi|hij|ijk|jkl|klm|lmn|mno|nop|opq|pqr|qrs|rst|stu|tuv|uvw|vwx|wxy|xyz|012|123|234|345|456|567|678|789)+

3 or more consecutive identical characters/numbers; e.g. 111, aaa, bbb, 222, etc.

> ([a-zA-Z0-9])\1\1+

https://regexr.com/4727n

This also works:

> (?:(?:0(?=1)|1(?=2)|2(?=3)|3(?=4)|4(?=5)|5(?=6)|6(?=7)|7(?=8)|8(?=9)){2,}\d|(?:a(?=b)|b(?=c)|c(?=d)|d(?=e)|e(?=f)|f(?=g)|g(?=h)|h(?=i)|i(?=j)|j(?=k)|k(?=l)|l(?=m)|m(?=n)|n(?=o)|o(?=p)|p(?=q)|q(?=r)|r(?=s)|s(?=t)|t(?=u)|u(?=v)|v(?=w)|w(?=x)|x(?=y)|y(?=z)){2,}[[:alpha:]])|([a-zA-Z0-9])\1\1+

https://regex101.com/r/6fXC9u/1

Answer (score 0):

for the first question this works if you're ok with less regex

```
         containsConsecutiveCharacters(str) {
            for (let i = 0; i <= str.length - 3; i++) {
                var allthree = str[i] + str[i + 1] + str[i + 2];
                let s1 = str.charCodeAt(i);
                let s2 = str.charCodeAt(i + 1);
                let s3 = str.charCodeAt(i + 2);
                if (
                    /[a-zA-Z]+$/.test(allthree) &&
                    (s1 < s2 && s2 < s3 && s1+s2+s3-(3*s1) === 3)
                ) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: there is regex in this,

Comment: Yes, true I edited the answer at some point. I don't get the down vote though, this pretty much works. it might not be ideal but it's not a wrong answer I assume, and the code is pretty self explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

- > 3 or more consecutive sequential characters/numbers; e.g. 123, abc, 789, pqr, etc.

  ```
  (?:(?:0(?=1)|1(?=2)|2(?=3)|3(?=4)|4(?=5)|5(?=6)|6(?=7)|7(?=8)|8(?=9)){2,}\d|(?:a(?=b)|b(?=c)|c(?=d)|d(?=e)|e(?=f)|f(?=g)|g(?=h)|h(?=i)|i(?=j)|j(?=k)|k(?=l)|l(?=m)|m(?=n)|n(?=o)|o(?=p)|p(?=q)|q(?=r)|r(?=s)|s(?=t)|t(?=u)|u(?=v)|v(?=w)|w(?=x)|x(?=y)|y(?=z)){2,}[\p{Alpha}])
  ```

  https://regex101.com/r/5IragF/1
- > 3 or more consecutive identical characters/numbers; e.g. 111, aaa, bbb, 222, etc.

  ```
  ([\p{Alnum}])\1{2,}
  ```

  https://regex101.com/r/VEHoI9/1

Answer (score 0):

All put together:

> ([a-zA-Z0-9])\1\1+|(abc|bcd|cde|def|efg|fgh|ghi|hij|ijk|jkl|klm|lmn|mno|nop|opq|pqr|qrs|rst|stu|tuv|uvw|vwx|wxy|xyz|012|123|234|345|456|567|678|789)+

3 or more consecutive sequential characters/numbers; e.g. 123, abc, 789, pqr, etc.

> (abc|bcd|cde|def|efg|fgh|ghi|hij|ijk|jkl|klm|lmn|mno|nop|opq|pqr|qrs|rst|stu|tuv|uvw|vwx|wxy|xyz|012|123|234|345|456|567|678|789)+

3 or more consecutive identical characters/numbers; e.g. 111, aaa, bbb, 222, etc.

> ([a-zA-Z0-9])\1\1+

https://regexr.com/4727n

Answer (score 0):

For case #2 I got inspired by a sample on [regextester](https://www.regextester.com/97975) and created the following regex to match `n` identical digits (to check for both numbers and letters replace `0-9` with `A-Za-z0-9`):

```
const n = 3
const identicalAlphanumericRegEx = new RegExp("([0-9])" + "\\1".repeat(n - 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

I was discussing this with a coworker and we think we have a good solution for #1.

To check for *abc* or *bcd* or ... or *012* or *123* or even any number of sequential characters, try:

```
.*((a(?=b))|(?:b(?=c))|(?:c(?=d))|(?:d(?=e))|(?:e(?=f))|(?:f(?=g))|(?:g(?=h))|(?:h(?=i))|(?:i(?=j))|(?:j(?=k))|(?:k(?=l))|(?:l(?=m))|(?:m(?=n))|(?:n(?=o))|(?:o(?=p))|(?:p(?=q))|(?:q(?=r))|(?:r(?=s))|(?:s(?=t))|(?:t(?=u))|(?:u(?=v))|(?:v(?=w))|(?:w(?=x))|(?:x(?=y))|(?:y(?=z))|(?:0(?=1))|(?:1(?=2))|(?:2(?=3))|(?:3(?=4))|(?:4(?=5))|(?:5(?=6))|(?:6(?=7))|(?:7(?=8))|(?:8(?=9))){2,}.*
```

The nice thing about this solution is if you want more than 3 consecutive characters, increase the `{2,}` to be one less than what you want to check for.

the `?:` in each group prevents the group from being captured.

Answer (score -2):

Try this for the first question.

returns true if it finds 3 consecutive numbers or alphabets in the arg

```
function check(val){
    for (i = 0; i <= val.length - 3; i++) {
      var s1 = val.charCodeAt(i);
      var s2 = val.charCodeAt(i + 1);
      var s3 = val.charCodeAt(i + 2);
      if (Math.abs(s1 - s2) === 1 && s1 - s2 === s2 - s3) {
        return true;
      }
    }

    return false;
}

console.log(check('Sh1ak@ki1r@100'));
```