# JQuery string manipulation to group numbers together

Tags: jquery

So I'm working with some tables and I'm attempting to store between numbers 1-16 now the information is being pulled from information in a string format such as:

1. `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16`
2. `1,2,3,4,5,6,11,12`
3. `1,2,6,7,8,9,10,12`

So i would like to group the numbers so if let's say there is more than 3 numbers in order e.g.: `1,2,3,4,5` this would become `1-3,5`

So the above would become:

1. `1-16`
2. `1-6,11,12`
3. `1, 2,6-10,12`

What sort of methods in jQuery can i take to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code solves your problem. I don't know if it covers all case, but I think it does. Feel free to adapt from here.

```
//var a = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16";
var a = "1,2,3,4,5,6,11,12";
//var a= "1,2,6,7,8,9,10,12";
var arr = a.split(',');
console.log('result', parseString(arr, arr[0], 0, arr[0]));

function parseString(arr, start, idx, res_string) {
    console.log(arr, start,idx, res_string);
    var starter = parseInt(start, 10);

    while (starter + 1 === parseInt(arr[idx + 1], 10)) {
        <!-- console.log(starter +1,parseInt(arr[idx + 1], 10)); -->
        idx += 1;
        starter += 1;
    }

    if (idx + 1 < arr.length && idx !== starter) {
        res_string += '-' + arr[idx] + ',' + arr[idx + 1];
        return parseString(arr, arr[idx + 1], idx + 1, res_string);
    }
    else if (idx === starter) {
        return parseString(arr, arr[idx + 1], idx + 1, res_string);
    }
    else if ( start === arr[arr.length -1]){
        return res_string;
    }
    else{
        res_string += '-' + arr[idx];
        return res_string;

    }
}
```

Comment: How would you handle something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/b1nth804/

Comment: Oh, I see... I guess I would need to spend more time on this. But like @user2957047 said, If you don't have the skills or patience to adapt the code I posted for your needs, it might be worthwhile to reconsider your design. The solution to what you are asking is not trivial. If you can provide more details I might be able to assist you

Comment: Well It works well for breaking up the string into sections so things like 1-16, 1-6,10-12, 1-10,13-14 are all perfectly outputted. However if there isn't a correct series of numbers so instead of 1,2,3,4,5,8,9,10,11 you get something like 1,3,5,7,8,9,10,11 you would be left with 1-1,3-3,5-5,7-11 we need to make it so that if the next number doesn't follow as it should we simply add the number so we go like 1,3,5,7-11

Answer (score 0):

JQuery is not what you need. You need some sort of algorithm or function that does array manipulation. This might help you -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/8905511/2957047. You may want to provide more details of what you're trying to accomplish. Modifying the design of your application might be easier.