# How to "summarize" an array of integers to a string with ranges?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

Lets say you have input `Array=[1,2,3,5,7,9,10,11,12,15]`

The output should be `1-3,5,7,9-12,15`

Im looking for feedback on my attempt and other possible solutions.
Heres my attempt in javascript:

```
var min = 0;
var max = -1;

function summarize(array) {
    var sumString = "";
    var prevVal = -1;

    array.forEach(function(currVal, index) {
        if (index > 0) {
            prevVal = array[index - 1];
        }
        if (index === 0) {
            min = currVal;
            max = currVal;
        } else if (currVal - prevVal === 1) {
            max = currVal;
        } else if (min !== max && max !== -1) {
            sumString += min + "-" + max + (index < array.length - 1 ? "," : "");
            min = currVal;
            max = -1;
        } else {
            sumString += min + (index < array.length - 1 ? "," : "");
        }

        if (index === array.length - 1) {
            if (max === -1) {
                sumString += "," + min;
            } else {
                sumString += min + "-" + max;
            }
        }
    });
    return sumString;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery string manipulation to group numbers together](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27209086/jquery-string-manipulation-to-group-numbers-together)

Comment: I think you should look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27209086/jquery-string-manipulation-to-group-numbers-together/27209483#27209483

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possible solution for positive numbers in ascending order. It features `Array.prototype.reduce`.

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 9, 10, 11, 12, 15, 23, 24],
    result = [];

array.reduce(function (r, a) {   
    result.push(r + 1 - a ? String(a) : result.pop().split('-')[0] + '-' + String(a));
    return a;
}, array[0]);  
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Questions. 1. Whats the benefit of using reduce vs forEach? 2. What do the parameters that you fed to stringify do?

Comment: to 1: in forEach, there is no parameter for the former value of `array[i-1]`. to 2: [`stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) has beside the value a replacer and a spacer parameter. i use only the spacer parameter, which gives 4 spaces indentation.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a slightly shorter implementation:

```
var i = 0, prev, arr = [1,2,3,5,7,9,10,11,12,15], out = [];
for(i=0; i<arr.length; prev = arr[i], i++) {

    // if the current number is not prev+1, append it to out
    // Note that we are adding it as a string, to ensure that 
    // subsequent calls to `split()` (see else part) works
    if(prev !== arr[i] - 1) out.push(String(arr[i]));

    // if the current number is prev+1, modify the last value
    // in out to reflect it in the RHS of - (hyphen)
    else out[out.length - 1] = [out[out.length - 1].split('-')[0], String(arr[i])].join('-');
}

// out => ["1-3", "5", "7", "9-12", "15"]
```

Comment: nice, can you please explain what happens in the `else`?

Comment: @FuzzyTree - Have added comments explaining what is being done in the `if` and the `else` parts.

Comment: can you explain how the prev-arr[i] is working in the for loop. When I did this `for(var i = 0; i <10; prev = arr[i], i++) {console.log(i); console.log(prev)}`. It logged undefined when i is 0.

Comment: @DanielKobe - The last section in a `for` loop (in this case `prev = arr[i], i++`), is executed **after** each iteration. So when `i` is 0, i.e. the very first iteration, `prev` has no value assigned to it and hence is `undefined`. Once  `i` becomes 1, `prev` will be `arr[0]`, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem recently, after some reflection, I noticed 3 different transformations: (1) Group consecutive numbers; (2) Transform groups into strings representing the ranges; (3) Join range strings on comma.

```js
function summarizeRange(items) {
  const sorted = items.slice(0).sort((a, b) => a - b);

  return sorted
    .slice(1)
    .reduce((range, item) => {
      const rangedIndex = range.reduce((ranged, rangedCollection, index) =>
        rangedCollection.indexOf(item - 1) > -1 ? index : ranged,
        -1
      );

      if (rangedIndex > -1) {
        range[rangedIndex] = range[rangedIndex].concat(item);

        return range;
      }

      return range.concat([
        [item]
      ]);
    }, [
      [sorted[0]]
    ])
    .map(range => range.length > 1 ?
      '' + range[0] + '-' + range[range.length - 1] :
      '' + range[0]
    )
    .join(',');
}

console.log(summarizeRange([0,3,2,6,19,20,22,21,1]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution :

```
var points = [1,2,3,5,6,31,7,9,10,11,12,15];
points.sort(function(a, b){return a-b}); //sort array in asc
var resultArr=[];
var max; var min;
for(i=0;i<points.length;i++) //loop
{
    if(i==0)
    {
        min=points[i]; //lowest number in arr
        max=points[i]+1; //assign next value
    }
    else
    {
        if(max==points[i]) //if value matches continue
            max=points[i]+1;
        else //next value is not an incremental one so push it to result arr
        {
            max=max-1;
            resultArr.push(min+(min!=max? "-"+ max :""));
            min=points[i];
            max=points[i]+1;
        }
        if(i==points.length-1) //last element of the arr so push it to result arr
        {
            max=max-1;
            resultArr.push(min+(min!=max? "-"+ max :""));
        }

     }
}
alert(resultArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

First step uses dashes to separate sequential numbers and commas if they aren't. Second step replaces `-#-` with `-`.

```
var X = [1,2,3,5,7,9,10,11,12,15];
var S = '' + X[0];
for (var i = 1; i < X.length; i++) {
    S += (X[i] == X[i - 1] + 1)? '-': ',';
    S += X[i];
}
while (/-[0-9]+-/.test(S))
    S = S.replace(/-[0-9]+-/g, '-');
alert(S);
```

For a sequence like `1,2,5,6` will output `1-2,5-6` which might not be what you're looking for, so an optional third step would be to replace `#-#+1` with `#,#+1`, i.e. restore the comma:

```
for (var i = 1; i < X.length; i++)
    S = S.replace(X[i - 1] + '-' + X[i], X[i - 1] + ',' + X[i]);
```