# Regular expression for without consecutive or sequential digits

Tags: java, android, regex

I want to validate my user input to meet below criteria.
It should consist of 4-7 numbers
It should not have consecutive numbers like 1111
It should not have sequential numbers like 1234

we can apply the range 4-7 by using {4,7} but not sure about remaining conditions.

Could you please suggest how can we achieve this for java

Comment: [How to ask questions on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)

Comment: More than suggesting, good to try something first and see what happens

Answer (score 1):

> It should consist of 4-7 numbers

As you mentioned this one's trivial:

```
^[0-9]{4,7}$
```

> It should not have consecutive numbers like 1111

This one just check that there is **no** match for:

```
([0-9])\1+
```

- Matches the same text as the previously matching group ([0-9]), more than 1 times (starting with duplicates of two numbers). If you have a more specific repetition criteria just use brackets as in first case.

> It should not have sequential numbers like 1234

I believe pretty much all regex engines do not perform numeric comparisons within the actual symbols matched. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8880088/regular-expression-to-match-3-or-more-consecutive-sequential-characters-and-cons). I'd try to use something else than regex for this, for example *a simple for loop starting from the second element comparing if the previous element is the current element plus one*. O(n)

Answer (score 1):

Use two sets of regex. Use one to match the obvious things like 1111|2222|3333|4444|5555|6666|7777|8888|9999|0000|1234|2345|3456|4567... and force fail. Then do the easy mode: '^[0-9]{4,7}$'

Your problem is trying to do it all on one regex. Search positively for the exclusions and for the permitted bits.

Comment: Issue here is the constraint of 4-7 digits. Following this approach would be from 1111|...|1111111 and so on. Might take a while to match _the obvious things_

Comment: Matching 1111 would by default match 1111111. You can in regex match those things though ^(\d)\1{3,6}$ should match any character and 3-6 more of those followed by an end. That one is certainly doable. The counting bits or things like 54321 are hard, but you could just enter them all in for all I care. These things are judgement calls for bad passwords sorts of things. You might as well just have a banned list of numbers and search those. It's vague in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use regex.

Algo >

1. stop if input is not number.

(try catch)

2. convert input str to number and array of number.

```java
   str.split("");

   Integer.parseInt(str);
```

3. use number to check range 4-7.

`(num>1111 && num<9999999)`

4. use array to check consecutive & sequential numbers.

```java
 if (numarr[i] + 1 != numarr[i + 1]) {//Not sequential}

 if (numarr[i]     != numarr[i + 1]) {//Not repeated}
```

5. print decisions.

```java
    public class myjava {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String str;
            str = "12346a";
            str = "12345";
            str = "22222";
            str = "12346";
            try{
                int num = Integer.parseInt(str);
                int[] numarr= getarr(str);          
                if((num > 1111 && num < 9999999) && !issequential(numarr) && !isrepeated(numarr) ){
                    System.out.println("valid user:"+num);
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("Invalid user:"+num);
                }
            }
            catch(java.lang.NumberFormatException e){
                System.err.println("ID is not number :"+e);
            }
        }
        private static boolean isrepeated(int[] numarr) {
            for (int i = 0; i < numarr.length - 1; i++) {
                if (numarr[i] != numarr[i + 1]) {
                    System.out.println("Not repeated");
                    return false; }
            }
            System.out.println("repeated");
            return true;
        }
        private static boolean issequential(int[] numarr) {
            for (int i = 0; i < numarr.length - 1; i++) {
                if (numarr[i] + 1 != numarr[i + 1]) {
                    System.out.println("Not sequential");
                    return false; }
            }
            System.out.println("sequential");
            return true;
        }
        private static int[] getarr(String str) {
            String[] strarr = str.split("");
            int[] intarr = new int[str.length()];
            for(int i=0;i < strarr.length;i++) intarr[i]=Integer.parseInt(strarr[i]);
            return intarr;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regular expression to avoid sequential digits:-

```
^(?!.*([0-9])\\1{2})[0-9]{6,}\$
```

This is assuming you want atleast 6 digits and that you can have sequential digits upto a length of 2. Let me break this up for you:-

`(?!.*([0-9])\1{2})` makes sure that none of the chars repeat more than twice in a row. If you do not want even 2 consecutive digits, then remove {2} from this part.

`[0-9]{6,}` looks for atleast 6 digits

As for the consecutive numbers part, I don't have a proper solution for that. You may use

```
"^(?!.*012)(?!.*123)(?!.*234)(?!.*345)(?!.*456)(?!.*567)(?!.*678)(?!.*789)(?!.*([0-9])\\1{2})(?=.*\\d)[0-9]{6}\$"
```