# I'm looking for a java regex that will return true if string contains any char more than 3 times

Tags: java, regex

> I'm looking for  a java regex that will return true if a string
>   contains any char[including special char _(underscore) and -(hyphen)] 
>   more than 3 times.
>
> example :  Heloooo --->True hellooo --->Flase  Heleoeoe---> False
>
> got one \w{0,2}$ working fine for JS but not for JAVA Can anyone help,
>   thanks in advance?

Comment: Perhaps this post can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8880088/regular-expression-to-match-3-or-more-consecutive-sequential-characters-and-cons

Comment: This question has been marked as a duplicate of a completely unrelated question. The one suggested by The fourth bird is actually what this question is a duplicate of.

Answer (score 0):

Your JS regex doesn't seem right, but this `(a|[^a])\1{3,}` should work.

Link to regex tester: https://regex101.com/r/MJjNhT/1

Comment: you can use this Platform https://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html#
 for java regex101 uses JS. Unfortunately, this regex didn’t work for me but thanks.

Comment: @sampadchakraborty Could you elaborate more on how it doesn't work? It seems to work for your test cases, at least. Perhaps I can help