# Ignore any number containing more than 3 repeated numbers

Tags: r

Suppose i have following id

```
74876593476
74877777777
74884784633
74822228765
74878645421
74820201111
```

i want to ignore any number contain more than 3 repeated numbers respectively, then the expected result is:

```
74876593476
74884784633
74878645421
74876593476
```

Answer (score 4):

Using the regex from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8880125/3962914) post, you may use `grep` -

```
x <- c(74876593476, 74877777777, 74884784633, 74822228765, 74878645421, 74820201111)

grep('(\\d)\\1\\1\\1', x, invert = TRUE, value = TRUE)
#[1] "74876593476" "74884784633" "74878645421"
```

Or if you are a `tidyverse` fan, you can use `str_subset` from `stringr` with the same regex.

```
stringr::str_subset(x, '(\\d)\\1\\1\\1', negate = TRUE)
#[1] "74876593476" "74884784633" "74878645421"
```

This will remove numbers that occur **more** than 3 consecutive times.

Comment: This seems to also return values with trailing zeros (e.g., 91526000000).

Comment: Why do you think it should not return that? I don't see anything mentioned in the post @jblood94

Comment: 0 is repeated more than 3 times in a row. "i want to ignore any number contain more than 3 repeated numbers". Trailing zeroes may be an exception in the OP's mind, but there's no indication of that in the post.

Answer (score 3):

We can try `grepl` to subset `x`

```
> x <- c(74876593476, 74877777777, 74884784633, 74822228765, 74878645421, 74820201111)

> x[!grepl("(\\d)\\1{3}", x)]
[1] 74876593476 74884784633 74878645421
```

Answer (score 2):

A solution that avoids converting to characters.

```
fNoRep <- function(x, k = 3L) {
  n <- ceiling(log10(x)) + 1L
  # get the digits as integers, plus an extra digit for each value
  i <- as.integer((rep.int(x, n)/10^sequence(n, 0))%%10)
  # set the extra digit to 10 in order to separate the values
  i[cs <- cumsum(n)] <- 10L
  # use rle to find runs longer than k
  lens <- rle(i)$lengths
  x[-unique(findInterval(cumsum(lens)[which(lens > k)], cs)) - 1L]
}

x <- c(74876593476, 74877777777, 74884784633, 74822228765, 74878645421, 74820201111, 91526000000)
fNoRep(x)
#> [1] 74876593476 74884784633 74878645421
```

Compare to the `grep` solution, which doesn't remove values with trailing zeros.

```
fNoRepGrep <- function(x, k = 3L) as.numeric(grep(sprintf("(\\d)\\1{%d}", k), x, invert = TRUE, value = TRUE))
fNoRepGrep(x)
#> [1] 74876593476 74884784633 74878645421 91526000000
```

The math-based solution is about twice as fast as the `grep` solution.

```
x <- sample(1e10:(1e11 - 1), 1e4)
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(math = fNoRep(x),
                               grep = fNoRepGrep(x))
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>  expr     min       lq     mean   median       uq     max neval
#>  math  7.5738  9.03255 10.30973  9.38525 11.81905 16.7631   100
#>  grep 19.9207 20.19140 20.67160 20.48535 20.94270 23.1786   100
```

Answer (score 1):

The regex answer is probably better, but here's an alternative using `strsplit` and `rle`.

```
x <- c(74876593476, 74877777777, 74884784633, 74822228765, 74878645421, 74820201111)

x[sapply(strsplit(as.character(x),""),\(x)!any(rle(x)$lengths>3))]

#[1] 74876593476 74884784633 74878645421
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert them to strings, use the grep() function to detect the triple repeated digits then filter out any entries where it's contained. Finally, use filter from dplyr to remove all cases where the triple digits were matched. The use of | in the call to grepl() allows multiple valid strings to be used

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rlang)

data <- tibble(id=as.character(c(74876593476,74877777777,11111,74884784633,74822228765,74878645421,74820201111)))


output <-  data %>% mutate(triple=grepl(x=id,pattern="111|222|777")) %>%
       filter(triple==FALSE)
```

Comment: `grep()` is not from stringr. It's part of base R.